# Python generator next method

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

For the `next` method of generator, I use the below example. I tried to find the Python documentation for `next` method, but failed, could anyone help to point out?

The purpose I want to find the official document is I want to look for all forms of `next` methods and meaning of the 2nd parameter `None` in my below example.

```
slice = (x**2 for x in range(0,100))
first = next(slice, None)
print first
for item in slice:
    print item
```

Comment: The second parameter is the default: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Comment: `Help on built-in function next in module __builtin__:

next(...)
    next(iterator[, default])
    
    Return the next item from the iterator. If default is given and the iterator
    is exhausted, it is returned instead of raising StopIteration.`

This is what I get from python interpeter `help(next)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, nice! If you could add a reply, I will mark it as answer to benefit other people.

Comment: @lokesh1729, thanks, do you know if there is an interactive interpreter in PyCharm?

Comment: in the bottom of PyCharm, you will have `RUN` `Python Console` `TODO` etc... you can run your code in console.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks @lokesh1729 and vote up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next()` is a *function*, so it is listed in the [functions documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

> `next(iterator[, default])`
>   Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its `__next__()` method. If *default* is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise `StopIteration` is raised.

The second argument then is the default, returned if `iterator.__next__()` raised `StopIteration`. If no default is set, the `StopIteration` exception is not caught but propagated:

```
>>> def gen():
...     yield 1
...
>>> g = gen()
>>> next(g, 'default')
1
>>> next(g, 'default')
'default'
>>> g = gen()
>>> next(g, 'default')
1
>>> next(g)  # no default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

The default is rather redundant for the specific example you gave, as the `(x**2 for x in range(0,100))` generator expression is guaranteed to have at least one result.

PyCharm can show you documentation for Python standard-library functions; just use the Quick Documentation feature (<kbd>CTRL-Q</kbd>).